# Problem with pixi.js to use DisplacementFilter

Tags: javascript, 3d, pixi.js

I try to do a fake 3D effect with a depthmap using pixi.js. Here my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3D Pikachu</title>
    <style>

        html, body {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.3.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        let app = new PIXI.Application({width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerheight});
        document.body.appendChild(app.view);

        let img = new PIXI.Sprite.from('https://i.imgur.com/e6fchfD.jpg');
        img.width = 1200;
        img.height = 800;
        app.stage.addChild(img);

        //Verify if let img was loaded successfully
        if(img != null) {
            console.log("loaded correctly");
        }

        depthMap = new PIXI.Sprite.from('https://i.imgur.com/BgM4MRI.jpg');
        depthMap.width = 1200;
        depthMap.height = 800;
        app.stage.addChild(depthMap);

        displacementFilter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(depthMap);
        app.stage.filters = [displacementFilter];

        window.onmousemove = function(e) {
            displacementFilter.scale.x = (window.innerWidth / 2 - e.clientX /20);
            displacementFilter.scale.y = (window.innerHeight / 2 - e.clientY /20);
        }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Does someone have an idea? The basic image doesn't appear even if I put the depth map code in a comment. I try some console.log, but no result who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo. Instead of :

> let app = new PIXI.Application({width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerheight});

You should have:

> let app = new PIXI.Application({width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight});

So **innerHeight** instead of **innerheight**.